# Correct way to implement Client Server GUI Application

Tags: sockets, design-patterns, uml

I've been looking for quite some time correct way to implement a client / server application GUI. Honestly, I have not found any useful information for this problem. So I made a simple design and want to show you, see you guys are saying. I want to know if it is correct, if you can improve or anything else. Here is the **UML** and the **pseudocode of serverside**. I hope you think, critique and advice. Sorry for the typos.

**My UML:**

[image: UML]

**PSEUDOCODE**

**Gui Main Class**

This is the main class where we instantiate the class manager clients and server class, which we passed as parameters, the client manager instance, the Listbox (GUI component) and the listening port.

```
Class GUI_Main
{
    ListBox messageList;
    Server server;
    ClientManager clientMng;

    void init()
    {
        clientMng = new ClientManager();
    }

    void startServer() 
    {
        server = new Server(messageList, clientMng, 5555)
    }

    void stopServer()
    {
        server.stopServer();
    }
}
```

**ClientManager**

This class is used to manage clients connected to our server.

```
Class ClientManager
{
    void addClient(Client client)
    {
        { ... }
    }

    void removeClient(int Index) 
    {
        { ... }
    }

    void sendData(String data, int clientIndex) 
    {
        { ... }
    }
}
```

**Server**

This class is used to accept new connections, also display messages received from clients and display them in ListBox (GUI component)

```
Class Server implements ClientEvents 
{
    ListBox messageList;
    ClientManager clientMng;

    Public Server(...)
    {
        { ... }
    }

    void listenConnections()
    {
        { ... }
        Socket tempSocket = ssocket.accept();
        Client client = new Client(self, tempSocket);
        client.start();
        clientMng.addClient(client);
        { ... }
    }

    void stopServer()
    {
        { .... }
    }

    void onReceive(Client client, String data)
    {
        messageList.add(data);
    }   
}
```

**ClientEvents**

```
Interface ClientEvents
{
    void onReceive(Client client, String data);
}
```

**Client**

This class is used to interact with the client, send / receive data

```
Class Client 
{
    ClientEvents server;

    Public Client( ... )
    {
        { ... }
    }

    void ioMonitor()
    {
        { ... }
        String data = socket.readData();
        server.onReceive(socket, data);
        { ... }
    }

    void sendData(String data)
    {
        { ... }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Can you explain the feature you are looking to achieve?

Comment: @Mitul thanks for response. As i said, I want to know if the way I have proposed is correct or not. And if it is not correct, then what design pattern would be the right way

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what do you mean by your classes. I can't say how their relationships should look like until I know their tasks.

Comment: @Gangnus thanks for your response. The application is about a chat client/server, but the serverside has GUI, so you can see all your connected clients and interact with them. Also you as serverside can create private chat with your clients. So i want to know if it's a good implementation / "design pattern" for a serverside. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, but you still haven't answered my questions - what has to do each of these classes? All of them are views? All of them belong to gui, but you have some special gui class - what is it?

Comment: @Gangnus, i just put a description of each class.

Comment: @SamYan And I immediately answered :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To the correct UML class diagram:

- the connections GUI-Server and GUI-ClientMgr are bad.

  - You should draw dependency (slashed line) with <<i>> (instantiate) on it from UI to these two.
  - The association arrows should go from UI to these two
  - The association arrows should have congregate (black diamond) on the UI end and dot (black circle) at the ends of arrows.
  - These two associations must have multiplicity 1 on the UI side, they do not exist without UI.
- You use name server for things that are Server and that are not. It is VERY bad.
- Client Events is not marked as interface.
- Server block should have simple Server name.
- Connection Server - ClientEvents must be <kbd>generalization</kbd> relationship, with empty triangle on the second side.
- Rename ClientEvents to ClientEventsNotifier or something as that.
- Draw dependency from ClientMgr to Client with <<a>> (access) on it.
- connection server-client should be reversed.

### Content:

I would register client listeners in the ClientManager, when adding clients. And unregister there, too. Are you sure, that it is Server, who needs the Client Events?

Comment: Your response seems to be correct enough :)) I'll fix the failures. Thank you very much @Gangnus.

Comment: @SamYan After that you could make another question and we'll speak over the new diagram.